# Image Rotation jquery

Tags: jquery, image, animation, transition, fade

I'm looking for a way to create a image rotation with jquery. I must animate four images with a transition. This effect must work clockwise.

Now I have a link: 
http://www.artega.de/

How work these example?

PS: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: You should be able to find enough tutorials explaining how to achive this by searching on Google. This sites main focus is to help people with code they wrote, not to write code on demand or explain things that could be easily found in tutorials. You could for example use this to get started: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.de/2009/05/replacing-images-at-time-intervals.html Once you tried it and are having a problems with concrete code you could ask here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle example to rotate an image :

```css
img {
    display: block;
margin: 20px;
}

img {
-webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    -o-transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;
}

img:hover {
transform: rotate(45deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="" />
```